# How to fix the server "Response" for the client to view the image?

Tags: python, opencv, flask, flask-restful

I'm writing a small application that involves image processing on the server. 
The client choose an image and send that on the server, the server do some fancy processing (with the OpenCV library) and return the new image to the client.

I have the following snippet.

This is my **server.py**:

```py
r = request

# Convert string of image data to uint8.
nparr = np.frombuffer(r.data, np.uint8)
# Decode image.
img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Do some fancy processing here. 
[...]

# Build a response dict to send back to client.
response = {"message": img_encoded.tostring()}

# Encode response using jsonpickle.
[...]

return Response(status=200,
                response=response_pickled,
                mimetype="application/json")
```

This is my **client.py**

```py
# Load the image.
img = cv2.imread("dog.jpg")

# Encode image as jpg.
_, img_encoded = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)

# Send HTTP request with image and receive response.
response = requests.post(URL,
                         headers=headers,
                         data=img_encoded.tostring())

# Get the image form the response.
json = json.loads(response.text)
image_data = json["message"]
img_grayscale = bytes(image_data['py/b64'], 'utf-8')

# Convert string of image data to uint8.
nparr = np.frombuffer(img_grayscale, np.uint8)

# Decode image.
img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

cv2.imwrite("processed.jpg", img)
```

I expect as output my file *processed.jpg* in my current folder that in fact there is, but, when I open that the following message occurs:

*You can open the file "processed.jpg" because it is empty.*

What am I missing? There is a specific standard (or pattern) to follow for converting and transferring images via HTTP from client to server, and, server to client?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you locally store the image temporary on the server. Then used python to download the image from that url of the image convert into numpy array. Just a work around

Comment: Yes, I can do obviously this, but, isn't my intention to storage (even temporarily) the image on the server for different reasons.